# Sql data from row to column with reference to another column

Tags: sql, database, select

**Parent table**

```
+====+===========+
| id | firstname |
+====+===========+
|  1 | abc       |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | bcd       |
+----+-----------+
|  3 | cde       |
+----+-----------+
```

**StudentRelationship table**

```
+==========+==========+===========+
| relation | parentid | studentid |
+==========+==========+===========+
| father   |        1 | s0001     |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| mother   |        2 | s0001     |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| father   |        3 | s0002     |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

**STUDENT table**

```
+=======+===========+==========+=========+======+
|  id   | firstname | lastname | address | sex  |
+=======+===========+==========+=========+======+
| s0001 | shdj      | khb      | jxx     | male |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+------+
```

It would be great if you could help me create a query which will return `studentid` ,`name`,`father name`,`mother name`,`sex`,`address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, then updated in your comments, I think this should work for you. I am sure someone with more advanced SQL skills can post a more elegant way to do this. But this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cte.studentid
    ,studentFirstName
    ,studentLastName
    ,father.fatherFirstName
    ,mother.motherFirstName
    ,sex
    ,address
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN father ON cte.studentid = father.studentid
LEFT JOIN mother ON cte.studentid = mother.studentid
```

---

The following is an example where a student (Jeff Jones) has two fathers (let's say one of them is the step-father):

[image: example]

A few recommendations here:

> 1. Take a course on SQL syntax fundamentals (any type MySQL, T-SQL, etc..)
> 2. Read about [FROM and JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql)
> 3. When posting your question here, the table examples should have better test data. "asdfkj", "shdsf", "Asdjkfdjkf" are horribly hard to
>      use to test code against because there is no context of what you are
>      looking at. I realize you are just posting an example, and the context
>      of the rows is partly insignificant, but it just makes for easier
>      question answering, and doesn't scare off people who would want to
>      answer your question.

---

Here is an [DEMO](http://rextester.com/MNKZ56329) you can play with, that has reasonable data in the fields you've mentioned.

Comment: but needed in one line  for every _studentid_ to be used in jquery datatable!! and there are about 4000 _studentiss'_

Comment: @RenukaChauhan there is no jQuery tag on this question. You want all results (about 4000) to be returned on a single row?

Comment: no,the i need  studentid ,student firstname,last name ,*father name,mother name*,sex, address in one line

Comment: @RenukaChauhan I have updated my answer, examples, and code test in the link above.

Comment: ur example with one more row of data in student is giving 4 rows of result..please check

Comment: @RenukaChauhan Ok, I will check this out tonight. Thank you

Comment: @RenukaChauhan Revised answer tonight, posted new DEMO and added more test data.